# How to merge multiple xml files with same name but in different subfolders using Python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, data-science

I have a folder with subfolders in each subfolder there is an XML file with the same name. I need to make a loop that goes over these subfolders, finds files with the same name, combines them, and saves them in a different folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm new to python, so I tried how to compare files in two folders using os.listdir(folder path), also I checked how to combine two xml files using ElementTree parse and getroot. but I do not know how to apply this for multiple files and folders

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If every subfolder has a file with the same name (assuming it's something like foldername.xml, how are there files with the same name that we need to combine ?). Are some files within the subfolder named the same and we need to group them ? There is one file by folder right ?